# Question about deleting old records from a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have a SQL Server table.

This table has a column that shows the datetime of when it was inserted.

How can I have something run that always deletes records that are 24 hours old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take a look at this: [How to: Schedule a Job (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

then just schedule your query:

```
delete from table_name where date_created < dateadd(d,-1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

I couple of things to add to this discussion...

1. To avoid scanning the primary key ensure there is an index (unique or not depending on the data) on the given datetime column.
2. Also review the execution plans of the statement you are trying to use and consider wrapping it in a transaction with a subsequent rollback so that you can repeat the process and evaluate the differences.

For example:
Comparing

```
date_created < dateadd(d,-1,GETDATE())
```

To

```
date_created < getdate()-1
```

Shows that the dateadd function adds considerable overhead to the evaluation and while it would be faster then scanning the PK it's always better to shoot for the fastest option altogether.

Comment: You could just insert the future date into a deleteAfter or expirationDate column, taking away any calculation in the delete statement and moving it into the insert.  of course your mileage may vary, so benchmark,benchmark,benchmark.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM <tableName> WHERE <col> < getdate()-1
```

Comment: Well my question was mainly how to set something like this up to always make sure there were no records in the database that were older than 24 hours, however, wouldn't this only delete records where the day was one prior, not taking into account hours, etc?

Comment: The `getdate()` function returns the current datetime; subtracting one from it will subtract 24 hours, keeping the time information intact (e.g. `select cast('2011-04-05 12:24:39.943' as datetime) - 1 = '2011-04-04 12:24:39.943'`).